# Pascal Precht's angular-translate vs. Rahul Doshi's angular-localization

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I'm using Pascal Precht's [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) (12.5 KB minified) + Alex Sexton's [messageformat.js](https://github.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js) (15 KB minified) for pluralization.

After watching AngularJS YouTube channel's video «[Internationalize AngularJS: Globalized Apps for a Global Audience](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6I_rONDvHq0)» about new i18n module for Angular, I'm wondering is it worth to move from *angular-translate* to Rahul Doshi's *angular-localization*?

As I see *angular-localization* is more «Angular way» + I can be free from lack of Angular's interpolation in *messageformat* syntax. Also, I usually do not care about my JS file sizes, but *27.5 KB* vs *4.5 KB* is a big difference.

So, does anybody has an experience with both *angular-translate* and *angular-localization* and can tell about differences/drawbacks/etc of them both?

(Also I'm creating this question because I did not find this two library comparison in Google in «*one vs. another*» format — developers like this kind of comparisons, so it will be easier to find it in future here on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

A big difference is the ability to load languages dynamically. Angular-localization doesn't offer that feature (or I didn't find it). You need to specify the location of the language files, angular-localization will load them automatically.

Angular-translate supports loading files automatically, but also supports custom loading of language files through the angular-translate-loader-static-files module.

Comment: Well, as far as a can see everything is fine with dynamically loaded files — when I open official web page http://doshprompt.github.io/angular-localization and go to the DevTools -> Network and try to change language to Francais in dropdown menu, I can see localization and pluralization JSON files are loaded and all examples are translated to French.

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn't clear. With dynamically loading files I meant to say that you can only tell angular-localization to find the language files at a certain location. Angular-translate enables specifing language files at config time. You can specify a static file loader (like angular-localization) but you also provide your own file loader.